# Converting for loop into additional column in dataframe

Tags: dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to convert output of the print function into a data frame.

Below the code:

```
import spacy
```

from spacy.matcher import Matcher
from spacy.util import filter_spans

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")

a = len(dataset)

for n in range(a):

```
txt = dataset["Text"].iloc[n]
doc = nlp(txt)
sentence = doc

pattern = [{'POS': 'NOUN', 'OP': '?'}]     


matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("Verb phrase", [pattern])

doc = nlp(sentence) 

matches = matcher(doc)
spans = [doc[start:end] for _, start, end in matches]
        
#print (filter_spans(spans))    
nouns = (filter_spans(spans))
#print(nouns)
dataset["Noun"] = dataset.assign(nouns.values)
```

How can i make output (nouns) as a additional column in my dataset?

Comment: You neglected to identify what language you are using.

Comment: Sorry, it is Python, Jupiter